# Was Light's threat fake?

Tags: death-note

In chapter 30 of the manga, Light threatened to kill Misa, but both of them are death note owners. So, was it even possible for Light to kill Misa even if he wanted to kill her?

Comment: Why do you think that it wouldn't be? Specifically, what has her being a Death Note owner got to do with anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents Death Note owners from being victim of a Death Note. Light was entirely willing and able to kill Misa when he threatened her, he stopped not because a rule was preventing it but because Rem threatened to kill Light if he kills Misa (Ch 30).

[image: Death Note Ch 30 Pg 19]

> If you kill this girl then I'll write your name in my Death Note and kill you. I can see her remaining  lifespan. If she dies before that, then I will assume you killed her. And of course, if I see you're about to kill her, then I'll kill you before you can do it.

With regards to Death Note owners killing each other, at least two examples come to mind, Light killing [Kyosuke "the Yotsuba Kira" Higuchi](https://deathnote.fandom.com/wiki/Kyosuke_Higuchi) at the climax of the Third Kira arc and Light puppeteering [Jack Neylon](https://deathnote.fandom.com/wiki/Jack_Neylon) to help him wipe out Mello's mafia buddies. In both cases, nothing in particular prevents Light from writing their names in the Death Note.

The Death Note has a rather extensive [list of rules](https://deathnote.fandom.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note/Manga_Chapter_Rules) gradually revealed to the reader with each chapter. Poring over the entire ruleset some rules pertain to who can and cannot be killed by the Death Note, E.G. "If a Death Note owner accidentally misspells a name four times, that person will be free from being killed by the Death Note. However, if they intentionally misspell the name four times, the Death Note owner will die." (Ch49) or "You cannot kill humans at the age of 124 or over with the Death Note." (Ch41). But none of the rules say anything in particular about killing Death Note owners the only rule of relevance is the first one "The human whose name is written in this note shall die." (Ch1).